# How does one use JS clearTimeout with parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to create a very simple function that would simulate window blind's movement. It is run on a server that will receive a request with `direction` parameter that says whether the blind should go `UP`, `DOWN` or it should `STOP`.

The simulation is supposed to work like this: request comes in with the `direction` parameter, server responds that the blind is `MOVING`. The movement, no matter the direction, will last 10 secs as it can be seen in the `setTimeout` function. The point is that if server receives a request with `direction === STOP` then the server should call `clearTimeout` to "stop" the blind's movement and return a different blind state, saying that the blind is `PARTLY_CLOSED`.

So far it works this way, that if I send a request with some direction, server responds with `MOVING` as it should. When I call `clearTimeout` during the "movement" it actually starts a second `setTimeout` function.

My question is: how do I make the code right and how do I parametrize the `setTimeout` function?

Here is the code:

```
let blindState = "OPENED";
const blindMovementFunction = (direction) => setTimeout((direction) => {
    console.log("### direction", direction);
    if (direction === "UP") {
        blindState = "OPENED"
    } else if (direction === "DOWN") {
        blindState = "CLOSED";
    }
}, 10000);
```

Usage inside the endpoint:

```
if (req.query.direction === "STOP") {
            console.log("### blindMovementFunction", blindMovementFunction);
            clearTimeout(blindMovementFunction);
            blindState = "PARTLY_CLOSED";
            res.send(blindState);
        } else {
            blindState = "MOVING";
            res.send(blindState);

            blindMovementFunction(req.query.direction);
        }
```

Comment: You're not using clearTimeout properly, it should be used with the id generated by a call to setTimeout.

Comment: @Axnyff could you expand your comment a little bit more? Every snippet is placed in another place in the code - first one is 'global' and second one is inside request's handler function. Where should I assign the ID? At the request handler function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the function reference to `clearTimeout`, it needs `timeoutID` returned by `setTimeout()`

Define in global scope

```
var timeoutID;
```

Persist the timeout-id return by `setTimeout()` method

```
timeoutID = blindMovementFunction(req.query.direction)
```

and

```
clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

Comment: thank you! Your solution worked and everything is fine now. There was some technical bump that was not connected to the code itself. Thanks again!